# Keyboard shortcuts 1,2, and 3 not working in edit mode

Tags: shortcut

just updated to blender 2.92 using it on an iMac 2019.
When in edit mode the keyboard shortcuts 1 2 and 3 do not switch between Vertex edges or Face mode.
Do I need to change something in the preferences?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I already had that checked. When I’m in edit mode and I press the 1,2, or 3

Comment: Please use the reply button under someone's answer to reply to them so that they get a notification and to keep things organized.

Answer (score 1):

[image]If you don't have Numpad and if u have emulated Numpad this could happen. The solution is, to map it manually. Go to Edit/Preference/Keymap/key-binding then search for 1. go to Mesh expand select mode, just press digit 1 this will change it as Numpad 1 similarly  assign for 2 and 3 it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I read the question wrong, I don't know any way to change between modes without doing it manually. Select between the circled things to switch between Vertex select, Line select, and face select. I don't think you can use 1, 2, 3 keys to switch them.
[image: select]

Comment: He isn't talking about the perspectives, but what select mode he is in ex. face select, edge select, and vertex select.

Answer (score 0):

You can click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>3</kbd> to switch between objects

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened to me, I just changed the changes in this sector uncheck *Emulate Numpad* and back to normal.

I'm using iMac 2020.

[image]